# PDF invoice to UBL/XML invoice convertor tool

Tags: ocr, invoicing, accounting

I have allot of PDF files which I need to get into my accounting software. The accounting software supports [UBL/XML](http://ubl.xml.org/) invoices ([sample](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xml/UBL-Invoice-2.0-Example.xml)).

I am looking for a tool (software, script etc.) or service to convert my invoices to this format. Preferably it's a software tool which is free or one time buy.

More info on [UBL on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Business_Language)

I already know of [Chimpkey](http://chimpkey.com/) <s>(they seem inactive)</s>. And I am looking for more so I can do a comparison.

The invoices are all different with various layouts, but here is a sample: 
[image: sample invoice]

Comment: Would you mind including a sample PDF invoice (as an image) into your question? (with fake name/address/amount) And ideally the resulting UBL/XML that you expect.

Comment: The invoices are all different, is it relevat to post one? If yes, i will grab one from Google images. As for the output, I thought UBL was a standard for exchanging invoices. So it should meet the standards. I don't have any specifications other then it should meet UBL.

Comment: Yes, one from Google Images is OK. To avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Just added one.

Comment: The problem, as you say, is that every company has it's own layout(s) - that makes it problematic.

Comment: That is a problem which would be perfectly solvable by software using templates, right? The thing is i am certian I am not the only one on the planet wanting this. So I guess there must be solutions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data extraction from PDFs is not necessarily a trivial solution; however, it's a good time to have this problem in that there are quite a few options based upon what "type" of user you are.  Probably the best overall software package (which I've used before to great success) is Tabula:

```
http://tabula.technology/
```

... it's open source, and I'm a full stack guy; so it's great from a dev's perspective (as well as being easily in the wheelhouse for a non-dev.)  Tabula allows you to extract that data into a CSV or Microsoft Excel spreadsheet using a simple, easy-to-use interface.  From there, it's trivial to export it to XML with either Microsoft Office or Libre Office... (as well as a myriad of online tools.)  Although, since you mentioned it's accounting software; all accounting software I've ever worked with will allow you to import directly from a CSV.

However, sometimes people want a solution with "support", i.e. a commercial application...  Here my recommendation is :

```
https://pdftables.com/
```

Finally, if you want more "control" over the flow; you can always look at creating your own "solution" by combining a couple of different Open Source items:

```
http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/
https://poppler.freedesktop.org/
http://www.pdfparser.org/
http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/portsntools.html
```

Comment: I'll come back and clean/expand this answer in a bit, but I gotta go pick up the kids.  :-)

Comment: I didn't vote it down. But it seems your tools are mainly focused on OCR. I am looking for a soluiton which generates UBL/XML which can directly be read by my accounting software. Obviously i don't want to code it myself.

Comment: @Akif  Thanks for the feedback... I'm not sure who downvoted or why?... (maybe they'll post a comment?) But I'm not sure why you think they're focused on OCR, when a number of them actually don't do OCR at all? For instance my top choice, Tabula, is not able to extract any data from image-based PDFs. Would you explain further?

Comment: @Akif Perhaps you missed my last comment?

Comment: Which of these solutions actually generates an UBL/XML output? Maybee I am doing something wrong or am missing details...?

Comment: @Akif I just updated my answer...  the top choice, Tabula, goes to CSV/Excel; from there it's easy to get to XML.  However, since you didn't tell us which accounting software you're using I can't say for certain; however, I'd be extremely surprised if it can't input data directly from a csv.  If you're not a programmer, I'd definitely recommend you start with Tabula.

Answer (score 0):

There is a company called Conexiom which offers a *service* that will do what you ask. They can convert Invoice and Purchase Orders into whatever file you want.  See www.conexiom.com.

Comment: Maybe so, but this site is for software recommendations not professional services.

Comment: The person knew about Chimpkey and wanted an alternative. Chimpkey is a service as well.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the answer of George, extracting data extraction of PDF files is not a trivial solution. This is because the PDF specification does not offer any syntactical markup like HTML does (e.g. , , ...). This makes it challenging for software products to "understand" the data.

The tools mentioned by George (Tabula.technology, pdftables.com, ...) are certainly great tools to extract tables from individual files. They won't help you though in case you want a fully automated process which converts PDF to UBL/XML.

I'm the founder of Docparser and we do exactly what you are looking for. We also just published an article on [UBL](https://docparser.com/blog/ubl-universal-business-language/) and [automated invoice processing](https://docparser.com/blog/invoice-ocr-software/). Hope this helps clarify the steps to take. I'd be more than happy to guide through our free trial.